# Query to fetch salesperson records who has same cities alloted

Tags: sql-server-2008

Following is a sample of my table

```
SalesPerson City
harry    Houston
John    Austin
Mick    Austin
Gary    Lansing
Trevor  Boise
Michael Trenton
Karen   Trenton
```

I want to know all the saleperon  who has the same city alloted to him/her.
So, the result from the above table should give me (John, Mick, Michael, Trenton)

How can i write a query without affecting the performance. I dont want to use COUNT function.

Thanks

Comment: The result set should probably be (John, Mick, Michael, Karen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT a.SalesPerson
FROM dbo.table a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM dbo.table b 
              WHERE NOT a.SalesPerson = b.SalesPerson
              AND a.City = b.City)
```

Not sure how performant it is, but it does not use Count.

Comment: I guess the logic is right, but this still gives all the records

Comment: worked, some other thing in my query which was causing the problem

Answer (score 1):

This query will help you

```
select t1.City,
    isnull(
    stuff(( 
              select ',' + convert(varchar,SalesPerson )
           from mytable
           where (City=t1.City)
           group by SalesPerson
           for xml path('')
          ),1,1,'')
          ,'') as person
 from
 (
    select City from mytable
 ) as t1
```

Output:

> Trenton Michael,Karen
>
> Austin  John,Mick
>
> Houston harry
>
> Lansing Gary
>
> Boise Trevor